# History of programmatic interfaces to iptables, ipchains, and ipfw

Tags: iptables, ipfw

I had to do some fiddling with `iptables` rules from Go recently, and I noticed both [docker's](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/master/iptables/iptables.go) and [coreos's](https://github.com/coreos/go-iptables/blob/master/iptables/iptables.go) wrapper libraries `exec()` out to the `iptables` command and screen scrape the standard output. This seemed surprising to me.

In Python-land, there's [python-iptables](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables):

> Interoperability with iptables is achieved via using the iptables C libraries (libiptc, libxtables, and the iptables extensions), not calling the iptables binary and parsing its output.

I guess a Python library is allowed to load C libraries at runtime, and Go can't [edit: I'm wrong], but couldn't Go statically link to those libraries? Because the Go library would have to get `libxtables.a` etc. from somewhere? (I'm `dpkg -L`ing the relevant `-dev` packages in Debian, and I only see `.so`s.)

Anyway, according to the [Netfilter FAQ](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-4.html#ss4.5):

> 4.5 Is there an C/C++ API for adding/removing rules?
>
> The answer unfortunately is: No.
>
> Now you might think 'but what about libiptc?'. As has been pointed out numerous times on the mailinglist(s), libiptc was *NEVER* meant to be used as a public interface. We don't guarantee a stable interface, and it is planned to remove it in the next incarnation of linux packet
>
> We are well aware that there is a fundamental lack for such an API, and we are working on improving that situation. Until then, it is recommended to either use system() or open a pipe into stdin of iptables-restore. The latter will give you a way better performance.filtering. libiptc is way too low-layer to be used reasonably anyway.

Ok, so maybe you're not supposed to treat those C libraries as stable. Then I thought "why not just talk to `/proc` or whatever directly?" Turns out, `iptables` mostly doesn't use `/proc` to talk to the kernel (just to read table names?), and the main interface is actually `getsockopt()` and `setsockopt()` on an unbound socket.

This was another surprise! (But maybe it's just because I'm unfamiliar with this kind of code that it seems like a funny way to interface with the kernel.)

I did a bit of archaeology backwards from `iptables` to `ipchains` to `ipfw` and found an [ipfw man page from 1997](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/ipfw.4.html) which made me feel a bit better:

```
BUGS
       The  setsockopt(2)  interface  is a crock.  This should be
       put under /proc/sys/net/ipv4 and the world would be a bet-
       ter place.
```

You can find elsewhere that "The ipfw utility first appeared in FreeBSD 2.0" and

```
HISTORY
      Initially this utility was written for BSDI by:
       Daniel Boulet    <danny@BouletFermat.ab.ca>
      The FreeBSD version is written completely by:
       Ugen J.S.Antsilevich <ugen@NetVision.net.il>
      while synopsis partially compatible with old one.
```

[Here's the FreeBSD 2.0 version of `ipfw` from 1994](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/release/2.0/sbin/ipfw/ipfw.c). It still uses `setsockopt()`, but seems to use `kvm_read()` instead of `getsockopt()`.

#### My Questions

- Please correct anything I said wrong above :)
- Why did they choose `{get,set}sockopt()` in the first place? Is it uncommon, or just new to me?
- Why didn't it get changed at some point? Like to something under `/proc` as the 1997 man page suggests.
- Why did they never come up with a stable/public C interface to `iptables`?

#### My Follow-up Questions

> "Not quite, the main interface is netlink’s NETLINK_NETFILTER family"

Thanks for this pointer!

I'm looking at https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree and only `libipq` seems to be using a netlink socket, unless I'm missing something.

```cpp
$ ick "socket\("
include/libiptc/libiptc.h
158:int iptc_get_raw_socket(void);

include/libiptc/libip6tc.h
152:int ip6tc_get_raw_socket(void);

utils/nfsynproxy.c
129:    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

libiptc/libiptc.c
1312:   sockfd = socket(TC_AF, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

extensions/libxt_set.h
14: int res, sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

libipq/libipq.c
223:                h->fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_FIREWALL);
225:                h->fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_IP6_FW);

libxtables/xtables.c
881:    sockfd = socket(afinfo->family, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

The `libipq` stuff looks "normal" to me: make a socket, bind it with a sockaddr, `sendto()`, `recvfrom()`, etc.

Also `xtables-monitor` seems to be using some `mnl_socket_*` wrappers which do netlink stuff.

But I can't figure out `libiptc` and `xtables` -- no mention of netlink, and they don't even bind the socket.

https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/libxtables/xtables.c#n881

https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/libiptc/libiptc.c#n1312

There are other examples that don't (seem to?) use netlink, like this code from mozilla's rr debugger: https://github.com/mozilla/rr/blob/master/src/test/netfilter.c

And netlink is Linux-only, from the year 2000 (2.2), while this `{get,set}sockopt()` stuff in (at least) `ipfw` is older, and in BSD-land.

I'm not really sure what my question is anymore :) How do the non-netlink sockets somehow communicate with the correct kernel-side thing without even `bind()` and a sockaddr?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess a Python library is allowed to load C libraries at runtime, and Go can't

Go *can* use shared C libraries.

> Turns out, `iptables` mostly doesn't use `/proc` to talk to the kernel (just to read table names?), and the main interface is actually `getsockopt()` and `setsockopt()`.

> Why did they choose `{get,set}sockopt()` in the first place? Is it uncommon, or just new to me?

(This answer previously stated, incorrectly, that the main interface is [`netlink`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html)’s `NETLINK_NETFILTER` family.)

You’re correct, `iptables` uses calls to `getsockopt` on unbound sockets of the appropriate type to interact with the kernel, which ends up calling into [the kernel’s `netfilter` code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.6/source/net/netfilter/nf_sockopt.c#L119). I suspect this is for historical reasons...

Incidentally, `getsockopt` and `setsockopt` work on sockets in a variety of states, including unbound, and they have to because they’re used to set options before connecting. The `netfilter`-via-`sockopt` connection is effectively a side-channel.

> Why didn't it get changed at some point? Like to something under `/proc` as the 1997 man page suggests.

There are probably a number of reasons, but one is no doubt backward compatibility — in Linux, user-space interfaces are never supposed to break. So while a new interface could be provided, the existing one would remain, which reduces the incentive to improve it or rewrite programs which already work.

As long as the `iptables` command-line tool could be used with not too much effort, and providing a better interface involved a lot more effort, change would be difficult. A properly-maintained `libiptc`-style library would have been a possibility too, but there was never much incentive for the `iptables` developers to do that.

> Why did they never come up with a stable/public C interface to `iptables`?

Because “they” never got round to it. Now `iptables` is being phased out in favour of [`nftables`](https://netfilter.org/projects/nftables/), which includes a number of libraries providing access at different levels of abstraction (`libnftables`, `libnftnl`, `libnfnetlink`). This uses `netlink`, which was designed as a sockets-based interface to transfer information between the kernel and user-space, and is a natural fit for tools such as `nftables` (and `iptables`). The `netlink` documentation lists the other families available; these cover quite a lot of kernel-hosted functionality. `netlink`.

You might find https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink useful to get started driving `iptables` from Go. (It needs a fair amount of work for that, but it’s better than starting from scratch.)

Comment: Thanks! I added some follow-ups to the bottom of my main question since they didn't fit here. I don't know if I'm making too much of a thing about this `getsockopt()` "weirdness" (as it seems to me), or if I'm wrong in tracing the lineage from ipfw -> ipchains -> iptables the way I'm doing :) Let me know.

Comment: I was barking up the wrong tree, the interface really is `getsockopt`, sorry about that.